Folland Theorem 2.15. How does this 'Let $N \to \infty$ and apply monotone convergence theorem' works?
I am reading Real analysis by Folland G.B. I have a slight doubt on this..
Theorem 2.15
If $(f_n)$ is a finite of infinite sequence in $L^+$ and $f=\sum_n f_n$, then $\int f = \sum_n \int f_n$
In the proof he proved this for $n=2$, and said that it will hold for any finite N, by induction.  so $$\int \sum_{n=1}^N f_n = \sum_{n=1}^N \int f_n$$ Upto this I understood... after that he wrote $\color{red}{"\textrm{Letting $N \to \infty$ and applying the monotone convergence theorem again, we obtain} \int f = \sum_n \int f_n} $.
I wasn't able to understand the thing which is in red. How to do that precisely?

Apply the monotone convergence theorem to $(g_N){N\in \mathbb{N}}$ where $g_N:=\sum{n=1}^Nf_n$

Define $g_N:= \sum_{n=1}^N f_n$. Then $(g_N)N$ is a non-decreasing sequence of measurable functions for which you can apply monotone convergence theorem on the left hand side of the equation to get $\lim{N \to \infty} \int g_N = \int \lim_{N \to \infty} g_N = \int f.$ For the right hand side it should be clear what the limit $N \to \infty$ does.

@Lukas understood... thank you
